# Show that if $\int_Efd\mu <\infty$ then the set of points in $E$ for which $f(\omega) = \infty$ has $\mu$-measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathscr{F}}$
To define the Lebesgue integral we used simple functions, so for my purposes if $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a measurable function and $(\Omega, \scrF, \mu)$ is a measure space then
$$
\int_Efd\mu = \sup\{I_E(s): 0 \leq s \leq f, s \text{ simple} \}.
$$
where $I_E(s) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \mu(D_k \cap E)$ where $s = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\chi_{D_k}$ is a regular representation of the simple function $s$.

**Problem:**    Suppose that $\int_E fd\mu < \infty$. Then
$
 \mu(\{\omega \in E \mid f(\omega) = \infty \}) = 0.
 $

> *Attempt:* Let $F = f^{-1}(\{\infty\})$ so that $E \cap F = \{\omega \in E : f(\omega) = \infty\}$. Note that $F$ is $\scrF$ measurable since $\{\infty\}$ is a Borel set so the preimage is measurable because $f$ is measurable. Then we consider the simple function
> $$
> \phi = n\chi_F + 0\cdot \chi_{F^c}.
> $$
> This constitues a regular representation because $F$ and $F^c$ are disjoint sets with $F \cup F^c = \Omega$ and of course $s$ is a simple function as a non-negative linear combination of characteristic functions. Moreover $0 \leq \phi$ evidently since $\phi$ takes values $\{0,n\}$. Moreover $\phi \leq f$, to see this note that
> $$
> \phi(\omega) = 
> \begin{cases}
> n & \text{ if } \omega \in F \\
> 0 & \text{ if } \omega \notin F
> \end{cases}
> $$
> In the case where $\omega \in F$ we have that $f(\omega) = \infty$ by definition of $f$ so $\phi(\omega) \leq f(\omega)$ moreover if $\omega \notin F$ then $\phi(\omega) = 0 \leq f(\omega)$ since it's target is non-negative. Therefore $\phi \leq f$ and so
> $$
> I_E(\phi) = n\mu(E \cap F) \in \{I_E(s): 0 \leq s \leq f, s\text{ simple}\}.
> $$
> By definition of the supremum it follows that $n\mu(E \cap F) \leq \int_E fd\mu <\infty$, and so $n\mu(E \cap F)< \infty$. But because this holds for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows that $\mu(E \cap F) = 0$ and so we are done.

Does this make sense? I tried to be very explicit with each step since I want to be sure I understand everything. Thanks in advance for the clarifications, and let me know if I need to elaborate anywhere.

Comment: Looks good to me. Eventually you'll have results like $E \subset F$ implies $\int_E f \leq \int_F f$ for nonnegative $f$ which make this more immediate to see.